# Moving objects from code in Silverlight for Windows Embedded 7 (SWE)

Tags: silverlight, embedded, windows-embedded

I am desperately looking for a code sample which would allow me to dynamically create and move graphic objects in Silverlight for Windows Embedded 7 (SWE).
I have found several examples of application where a pre-defined storyboard is compiled into C++ application using SWI and the animation is then started using this storyboard. That is not what I am looking for.
I need an application where I internally have a list of objects for those I can dynamically set the position. An application showing how to implement a snowfall with several types of snowflakes dynamically animated or ballons flying randomly would be the closest to what I would like to see.